# Run automation test on android device from a automation app

Tags: android, ui-automation

I want to make an android app which  will install and start another app and then perform the UIautomation tests on that app.
Well currently i know how to intall another apk from my app , but the question is can i call the UIautomation from my app for anther app in question.
I want my app to work as a tool to work as a automation tool which will start automation of a particular app without going through the adb commands of pushing the automation jar and starting the test.